# Trouble with Graphics/Unity/nVidia

Tags: unity, nvidia, graphics

I used to use Ubuntu 14.04 on my HP Pavilion 15 for more than a year now. But recently I upgraded to 16.04 about a month ago or so, and things went smoothly until just today.

I'm not sure what caused this, maybe an update of some package, I have no idea, but all of a sudden my system wouldn't recognise the display card properly. I kept checking all existing remedies and remedy attempts I could find on-line. All I could manage to get right is for the system to boot into the graphic log-in screen (though sometimes it doesn't, and I have to reboot a couple of times).

Even when the graphical log-in screen does finally appear, no upper-border icons are to be found. And on logging in, only the background is to be seen, nothing else whatsoever. Even after trying all I could find about this (purging, re-installation, etc.).

There also seems to be a problem with dbus-launch communicating with DBus Daemon. I noticed this on trying to launch some GUI-based programmes from the shell to DISPLAY=:0.

Any help would be much appreciated.

A million thanks in advance.

Hosam Adeeb Nashed

Comment: These may help http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics/760935#760935 http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears

Comment: Have you tried reseatting the video card in its slot? Have you checked to see if there's a firmware update for the video card? Does it work correctly if you boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD? Cheers, Al

Comment: Since it's a laptop there's no question about PCI slots. And I did purge and update the nvidia package to 370 (I read it was the latest release). The machine dual boots with Win 10, and the card works just fine over there.

Comment: Thanks @Zacharee1, but these were among the first links I did follow. To no avail, though. So far, at least...

Comment: More details:
1) Sometimes, on booting up, I receive an alert to the effect that my graphics configuration is incorrectly set. If I click OK, then later Cancel, with luck I'm presented with the log-in screen, but with no networking, even if I try to start it manually from the shell (!!!).
2) I tried to coax gnome-terminal to open on :0 but to no avail; dbus-launch couldn't connect to DBus Daemon (as stated in my initial posted question).

Comment: Today I downloaded the ISO image of Ubuntu 16.04.1 and tried to boot from it (my upgrade path was through the net, not the DVD). Things worked, which means there's nothing wrong with the hardware itself.

Comment: Does anyone know the right way to manually configure xorg.conf so as to try using the open source driver rather than nvidia's proprietary one?

Comment: While booting off the Live DVD, I tried to see how the display card is configured, but failed to find an xorg.conf at /etc/X11, and didn't know where else to look...

Comment: Every time I boot the machine something different happen! Sometimes I receive an error alert stating that xorg is not configured properly. Other times I reach the log-in screen without errors, but with Dash not present (and naturally Unity isn't working). Networking might be working or not! Sometimes the error alert, when dealt with, might lead to the log-in screen or a black one with no prompt. Can anybody make sense of any of this???!!!!!

Comment: Today I tried to swap "nvidia" and "intel" in the [Layout] of the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file, hoping to boot into a usable screen. On rebooting, I found the file re-written to its previous state.

Comment: I also tried the GRUB way, clicking E on booting up, adding "nouveau.mode=0" at the end of the line starting with "linux", as prescribed on another post. Still, no luck...